# Installation error: Unable to install "composer-reset-server" npm module

Tags: node.js, npm-install, hyperledger-fabric

Trying to setup HL environment([install instructions](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html)) on my MacBook, unable to install "composer-reset-server" npm module, seems like the webpage is down, any other alternative url to install this module ? 
[Install error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoEeH.png)

Comment: its `composer-rest-server`, not `composer-reset-server`

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the typo, could install now.